# ios pod install returns "No podspec found for `FBSDKCoreKit"

Tags: react-native

I have a RN app which works on Windows.  I pulled down the code to my Mac and I'm trying to run the code on my Mac.  When I run pod install on my project's ios directory, the following error is output to the Terminal:

> No podspec found for `FBSDKCoreKit`

Here is the full Terminal output:

> My-MacBook-Pro:ios myname$ pod install Detected React Native module
>   pods for RNCAsyncStorage, RNFirebase, RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated,
>   RNVectorIcons, react-native-fbsdk, and react-native-safe-area-context
>   Analyzing dependencies Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from
>   `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
>   [!] No podspec found for `FBSDKCoreKit` in
>   `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBSDKCoreKit`

What is the most likely root cause of this error and what troubleshooting steps would you recommend?

Comment: Can you try this solution? 
https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/issues/80#issuecomment-279768985

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Make sure the path is there

`../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBSDKCoreKit`

2) Run a `pod repo update` and a `pod install`

If still not working I would try an `unlink` followed by a cleanup of any old links related to that library in `project.pbxproj` then `link` the library again.

Note: in some cases a `pod deintegrate && pod install` helped me with link errors like this.